# How to Achieve Custom Animated Weather MapKit Overlay - iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, weather

How would I go about achieving a custom animating weather Mapkit overlay?  I would like to implement a feature in one of my apps, where the user can press "play" and the weather overlay animates (Almost like a gif?) for the timeline.  This effect can be seen in many weather applications such as The Weather channels app, Weatherbug, AccuWeather ect...

I have tried to tackle this problem by adding Gif support to my app, and overlay the gif with the map, however this does not work because in order to overlay an image with MapKit I had to first convert the image to a CG Point, therefore taking my gif and overlaying a still image of it.

Does anyone have any idea where  I can start/how I can implement this?

Note: I have already looked at one third party weather library, the problem is that I already have the data, i just need to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in a rough manner by cycling through images and replacing the overlay image, not ideal, but it gets the job done.